# Compare enum with integers

Tags: c#, enums

Please refer the below enums

```
public enum Fruit
{
 Apple = 1,
 Orange = 2,
 Banana= 3
}

public enum Color
{
 Orange = 1,
 Yellow = 2,
 Red= 3
}
```

Now I want to map Fruit with Color.So I implemented

```
public enum FruitColor
{
 1= 3,
 2= 1,
 3= 2
}
```

I am getting an syntax error when I implement FruitColor

> Identifier Expected

How to resolve this?

Comment: Member identifiers are not allowed to begin with numeric values.

Comment: Use a `new Dictionary<Fruit, Color>()`. And please note that there are also *yellow* and *green* apples!

Comment: Sounds like a job for an custom attribute, or a `switch` statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no point in using an `enum` to map enum values. I would use a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<Fruit, Color> FruitToColor = new Dictionary<Fruit, Color>
                                          { { Fruit.Apple, Color.Red }
                                          , { Fruit.Orange, Color.Orange }
                                          , { Fruit.Banana, Color.Yellow }
                                          };

Color colorOfBanana = FruitToColor[Fruit.Banana]; // yields Color.Yellow
```

Answer (score 2):

Also just putting it out there because I can, the only advantage is you can encode other data in a custom attribute. However, I'd go with the dictionary or a switch ;)

**Given**

```
public enum MyFruit
{
    [MyFunky(MyColor.Orange)]
    Apple = 1,
    [MyFunky(MyColor.Yellow)]
    Orange = 2,
    [MyFunky(MyColor.Red)]
    Banana = 3
}

public enum MyColor
{
    Orange = 1,
    Yellow = 2,
    Red = 3
}

public static class MyExteions
{
    public static MyColor GetColor(this MyFruit fruit)
    {
        var type = fruit.GetType();
        var memInfo = type.GetMember(fruit.ToString());
        var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof (MyFunkyAttribute), false);
        if (attributes.Length > 0)
            return ((MyFunkyAttribute)attributes[0]).Color;
        throw new InvalidOperationException("blah");
    }
}

public class MyFunkyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyFunkyAttribute(MyColor color) { Color = color;}   
    public MyColor Color { get; protected set; }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var someFruit = MyFruit.Apple;
var itsColor = someFruit.GetColor();
Console.WriteLine("Fruit = " + someFruit + ", Color = " + itsColor);
```

**Output**

```
Fruit = Apple, Color = Orange
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fc2I15)

Comment: While overly complex, it is a good solution when things get more complex than in the question. Good effort!

Answer (score 0):

Member identifiers are not allowed to begin with numeric values, you can however use a method to get the proper values from each `enum`:

```
public Fruit GetFruit(this Color c) {
    switch ((int)c) {
        case 1: return (Fruit)3;
        case 2: return (Fruit)2;
        case 3: return (Fruit)1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reverse of this method would give you the `Color` from the `Fruit`. You can call this method via the `Color` type as a static method:

```
Fruit myFruit = Color.GetFruit(Color.Orange);
```

Comment: Why would you write `(Color)c` when `c` is already a `Color`? Also, you cast `3`,`2` and `1` as `Fruit` but you do not do it with `0`. Does this compile?

Comment: @Rafalon you are right. These castings are unnecessary. But of course it compiles. You can chain how many casts you like `int a = (int)(long)(int)(long)(short)(long)(int)2;`

Comment: `(Color)c` was meant to be a cast to `int`; casting 1, 2, and 3 as `Fruit` is the only way to compile. `0` is the only value that can be returned without being cast.

Comment: Yeah my question about compile-ability was mostly about that `0` not being cast, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: No problem, the cast is necessary in this case as no implicit conversion exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have numbers as enum keys. You could use a dictionary to map the values:

```
var map =  new Dictionary<Fruit, Color> 
           {
              { Fruit.Apple, Color.Red },
              { Fruit.Orange, Color.Orange },
              { Fruit.Banana, Color.Yellow }
           };
```

To access the mapped values use:

```
var mappedValue = map[Fruit.Apple];
```

Alternatively, because you want to map the inverse value (1 to 3 and 3 to 1) you could use casts from an integer, although this could be dangerous because the result could be undefined.

```
var src = (int) Fruit.Apple; // src = 1;
var tar = 4 - src; // tar = 3;
var mapped = (Color) tar;
```

More generic example:

```
function Color Map(Fruit fruit) 
{
   var src = (int) fruit;
   var tar = 4 - src;
   var color = (Color) tar;   
   return color;
}
```

Comment: _1= 3, 2= 1, 3= 2_ is not inversed. For 1<x<3, 4 - x = {3, 2, 1}. When op say it's {3, 1, 2} a shift on the right.